# «Кто» с глаголом?

Tags: глаголы, местоимение

В предложении: «Кто или что оказалО на вас влияние». Как согласовывать глагол?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: ***Кто или что оказалО на вас влияние?***

Согласование в ед. числе с ближайшим подлежащим.

[**§190. Согласование сказуемого с однородными подлежащими**](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_08)

> **3.** Форма единственного числа сказуемого предпочитается при смысловой близости однородных подлежащих, например:
> <...>
> **2)** сказуемое следует за подлежащим: *С зимой холодной нужда, голод настает* (Крылов); *Неточность и запутанность выражений свидетельствует только о запутанности мыслей* (Чернышевский); *Эта простота и ясность мышления заключает в себе задатки новой жизни...* (Добролюбов); ***Никто и ничто не нарушало тишины***.

Comment: Спасибо за правку!